# Issue rendering a line chart (Microcharts)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am working on aligning a LineChart (from Microcharts library) in a xamarin forms application. As this chart does not have obvious properties for customization (or perhaps I am not aware of those right now), I am wondering how to achieve the following functionalities:

1. How to remove gaps around the chart?
2. How to give color to the point, I do not want to color a line?
3. How to remove the shaded area below the line (I just want a line and the points displayed on the chart)?

[Code sample](http://www.filedropper.com/linechart)

Thank you

[image]

Comment: [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please..

Comment: @prateek I have updated my post with the code sample. here is the link for you: http://www.filedropper.com/linechart

Comment: If you want to remove shaded area below the line, you can add ` lc.LineAreaAlpha = 0;` in your background code.

Comment: Question 1 and 2, I cannot found way to ahcieve it, I suggest you to use ` OxyPlot` to achieve the line chart.https://oxyplot.readthedocs.io/en/master/getting-started/hello-xamarin-forms.html, Here is simple https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/OxyPlot-Xamarin.Forms-Sample

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT thank you, will checkout OxyPlot!

Comment: I tried the Oxypot, I wirte a demo, Here is running screenshot https://imgur.com/a/mCoC7z6 , Is that your needs?